# WP + W3c Total Cache brokes responsive menu on Minify

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, caching, responsive-design

i have a responsive website and i have activaded w3c total cache.
whenever i Minify, the responsive menu is misssing.
This menu is activated on specific screen sizes, the code is:

```
<div class="main-nav">
  <div id="responsive_current_menu_item">Welcome to Yum Yum Videos!</div>
    <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="menu">
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <a id="responsive_menu_button"></a>
</div>
```

The problem is, that whenever i minify, the `id="responsive_current_menu_item"` and `id="responsive_menu_button"` simply dissapear from code.

you can see it in action [here](http://www.pabloscillia.com.ar/clientes/yumyum/) (is the top menu, w3c tocal cache is deactivated in order to show responsive menu)

any idea where i might take a look please?
thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a issue like this changing the minify setting in performance section,of course i've restored everything with empty cache button before.I think the bug is created by the compressed code...

Answer (score 0):

We would need a little more input about how your menu works.

Just a guess: You responsive menu depends on jQuery, but jQuery is being loaded **after** the JS-Code for your menu has been loaded. It can't work that way. Try to change the minifying order and set the jQuery script to be loaded as first JS in all templates, embedded in the header.

Same applies to CSS-minifying.